# TypeError: this.state.albumlist.map is not a function

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I keep getting the error `TypeError: this.state.albumlist.map is not a function` when i try to display the data.

I can't find the issue in my code that is causing this. Can someone help me?

Here's my code:

(The code here was originally provided via several image links. I chose to edit in the code shown in the images the links referred to.)

```
import React from "react";
import datasource from "./dataSource";
import Card from "./Card";
import "./App.css";
//import albums from "./albums.json";
import SearchForm from "./SearchForm";
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state {
    albumlist: [],
    searchResults: []
    };
}
//state = {albumlist : [], searchphase: ""};
componentDidMount() {
    //this.setstate({albumlist: albums})
    this.loadAlbums();
}
```

```
//, { mode: 'cors' }
loadAlbums
async () => {
    const response = await dataSource.get("/album");
    this.setState({albumlist: response.data});
    console.log(response.data);
}
updateSearchResults = async (phrase) => {
console.log("phrase", phrase);
this.setState({searchphase: phrase});
const response = await datasource.get('album/search/description/" + phrase);
+
this.setState({albumlist: response.data});
}
```

```
rendered List = () => {
return (
this.state.albumlist.map
(album) => {
// if( album.description.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchphase.toLowerCase()) ||
return (<Card key = {album.ID} albumtitle={album.TITLE}
albumDescription={album.DESCRIPTION}
imgurl={album. IMAGE_NAME}
buttonText="Buy Now" />);
// else {console.log(album, "does not much", this.state. searchphase);}
}
)
);
};
```

```
render() {
return
<div>
<div className="container">
<SearchForm onSubmit={this.updateSearchResults} />
</div>
<div className="container">
{this.renderedlist()}
</div>
</div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

Comment: it's really difficult to go through 4 images to check the code. Could you please put it as a text? About your issue: most likely you are getting undefined from the backend response. Try to console log this response

Comment: Can you post the code of the `dataSource.get` ? as well as the response you get from the server

Comment: import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    
});

Comment: i am calling the api from an Express app - Backend

Answer (score 0):

Probably the response of API is undefined. You can add optional sign after your state to avoid this error but actually you must correct the API.

```
renderedList = () => {
    return (
        this.state.albumList?.map(album => 
            <Card />
        );
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry! but what do you mean by correct the api

Comment: The response of API (response.data) is an array?
It must be an array otherwise you got the error

Comment: it is an array - from albumList

Comment: I needed to add(response.data.data) it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
loadAlbums
async () => {
    const response = await dataSource.get("/album");
    this.setState({albumlist: response.data.data}); // needed to access the array by calling the the data 
    console.log(response.data);
}
```